# Update sales_quote_item programtically

Tags: magento-1.9

The below changes qty in sales_flat_quote_item to mu custom quantity but removed my custom pricing. How can I only update the qty?

```
 <?php
  $quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
 $quote->updateItem($itemID, array( 'qty' => $qty));
  $quote->save();
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$item = Mage::getModel('sales/quote_item')->load($itemId);
$item->setQty((double) $qty);
$item->save();
```

Comment: I get this error Call to undefined function setQty()

Comment: Updated the answer. Try now.